# Blank white image balloons in Google Earth

Tags: 14.04, google-earth

I've asked this a long time ago and never got an answer, but that was a different version of Ubuntu on a different machine. Now I'm running 14.04 on a ThinkPad T60, and still have the issue: when I click on a Panoramio image icon in Google Earth (the latest version; 7.1.4.1529) all I get is a blank white box. Panoramic images (the red square icons) seem to work just fine, though. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A different Ubuntu version had the same problem? This sounds like an issue with the GEarth app and not Ubuntu itself.

Comment: I never said that I thought it was a problem with Ubuntu. All I said was that it just happened on two Ubuntu installations.

Comment: If you don't think it's an Ubuntu problem, why are you asking on AskUbuntu? [unix.se] or [su] would be better options.

Answer (score 0):

I'am lookin longer than a year for a solution of this problem.
Now I found it and it works great :-)

Install the actual 64bit version of Google-Earth:
https://www.google.com/earth/index.html

Follow the instruction on this site to solve the problem:

https://bkjaya.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/how-to-solve-blank-panoramio-photo-problem-in-google-earth-on-ubuntu-2/#content

Notice that it only works for the 64 bit version of Google-Earth and begin in the terminal at:

Solution(given by Mr.Amirpli):......

Greetings 
Lars from Roermond/Netherlands